# How to save all the numpy arrays in a dataset as images with extension .png in local?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

Currently the below code saves only one image in my local folder. What's wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

```
import numpy
import png
for image in X2:
    png.from_array(image, mode="L").save("/Users/User/Downloads/{:'seq_{:06d}.png")
```

Here X2 is a dataset with all the numpy arrays

Comment: It seems like you are saving all your arrays with the same name.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, could you please help me with a better code?

Comment: `for number, image in enumerate(X2, 1): ... save(f".../{number:06d}.png")`

Comment: python syntax. look up "f-strings".